# MUI ThemeProvider customTheme overwriting some defaults

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I created a simple custom theme component

```
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';

const customTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        mode: 'light',
        primary: {
            main: '#6c5078',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#c09c8e',
        },
        error: {
            main: '#8e3030',
        },
    },
});


export default function Themed({ children }) {
    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
            {children}
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

and am trying to wrap a Mui Appbar with it. I'm having an issue with the custom theme overwriting SOME of the defaults.
Here is my Appbar

```
const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
        }),
        ...(open && {
            width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
            marginLeft: `${drawerWidth}px`,
            transition: theme.transitions.create(['margin', 'width'], {
                easing: theme.transitions.easing.easeOut,
                duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
            }),
        }),
    })
);

const Navbar = ({ ...props, children }) => {
    return (
        <AppBar {...props}>
         {children}
        </AppBar>
    )
}
```

when I logged out the theme (provided with styled() ) it was missing the whole default themes.transitions object. but once I removed the custom theme it was there.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong??